# Why my API call works on my local server and not online? (error 500)

Tags: php, laravel, api, deployment, http-status-code-500

I have two different website (two different domains) which use laravel.
One of them (which I'll call here api.com) provides an api with different routes and is actually on a local server (111.111.1.111) :

routes/api.php :

```php
Route::prefix('news')->group(function () {

    Route::get('', [ApiController::class, 'newsIndex']);
    Route::get('{id}', [ApiController::class, 'newsShow']);
});
```

ApiController :

```php
    public function newsIndex()
    {
        $news = News::orderByDesc('ordre')
                    ->where('site_destination', 'like', '%other%')
                    ->where('statut', '=', 1)
                    ->get();

        return response()->json($news);
    }

    public function newsShow($id) 
    {
        $news = News::findOrfail($id);

        return response()->json($news);
    }
```

I have to call these APIs from my second website (which I will call here request.com).
I want to deploy this one online (planethoster server). I succeed to deploy it but my page where I called API from api.com doesn't work : return 500 error.

Into my controller on request.com :

```php
    public function index() 
    {
        $newsListFromApi = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://111.111.1.111/api/news"));
        $newsFirstPictureList = [];
        foreach ($newsListFromApi as $key => $value) {
            $newsFirstPictureList[$value->id] = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://111.111.1.111/api/news/" . $value->id . "/firstPicture"));
        }
    
        return View::make('client.news.index', [ 
            'newsListFromApi' => $newsListFromApi,
            'newsFirstPictureList' => $newsFirstPictureList,
         ]);
    }

    public function show($newsId)
    {
        $news = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://111.111.111/api/news/" . $newsId));
        $newsDocs = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://111.111.1.111/api/news/" . $newsId . "/docs"));
        // dump($newsDocs);
        return View::make('client.news.show', [
            'news' => $news,
            'newsDocs' => $newsDocs,
        ]);
    }
```

If request.com is on localhost (production or development mode) it works fine. I only have warning message in console about mixed contents that I'm aware of. But if I deploy request.com I have a 500 error.

On the logs I have this entry :

```
*[2022-06-13 13:55:03] production.ERROR: file_get_contents(http://111.111.1.111/api/news): failed to open stream: Connection timed out {"userId":x,"email":"xx","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(http://111.111.1.111/api/news): failed to open stream: Connection timed out at /home/xx/laravel/releases/20220613-120400/app/Http/Controllers/Client/NewsController.php:12)
[stacktrace]
```

The api.com et request.com api aren't on the same server on development.

Do you think that it can be caused by the mixed contents error? I think that the browser will only not display images but display the page anyway...

Also I think it can be a problem of cross origin but I hadn't such an error message of it.

I suppose, thanks to the log, that it has a problem with this line of code when I call the API :

```php
$newsListFromApi = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://111.111.1.111/api/news"));
```

I am used to call API on JS with fetch(Ajax) but not with PHP...

Why does it work locally, but not online?

Comment: If they are not on the same server then you need to ensure that the api.com server is accessible from the request.com server. How you would ensure this depends on your infrastructure so it could be anything from firewall rules, security group rules, IP blocklists etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to your local server from outside of your network only if it has public access (open TCP/IP ports and public IP). `http://111.111.1.111` is a local IP address in this context.

You could deploy your API service to another server, and then the two would be able to connect.

Comment: OK I understand right now. I cannot use an API located on a local server from outside. The api.com will be deploy but not now. So I have to wait. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Petitemo, it's possible, but you'd have to make your local server public first. How to do it depends on what infrastructure it is running. It could be safer to deploy it somewhere instead of exposing your PC to the public.

Comment: I also think Nikolai. It would be safier to deploy it and not making a backdoor to my local server. Thanks for your advice!